# How to create a custom function that emulates the RANK formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, rank, google-sheets-custom-function

Using Google Forms, I am collecting data for teachers to use in determining students who qualify for Title 1 services.

The form feeds the data to Google Sheets, and I want to automate the process of summing scores by category and then ranking them in each category.

I have this code that copies the summaries from one column to another, but then I need to rank the column and that's where I'm stuck. Can someone help me understand how to rank the data?

I think I may need a `for` loop - but I'm stuck.

```
function CopyRankData() 
{
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SourceSheet=spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Ranking')
  var srcRange = SourceSheet.getRange('D1:D31');
  var destSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Ranking');
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange('I1:I31');
  srcRange.copyTo(destRange);
  --Need to Rank the column ---[Link to spreadsheet][1]
}
```

Comment: Precisely, what do you mean by ranking the data?

Comment: I want to write the code in the function above to perform this calculation: =RANK(M2,$M$2:$M$8,1).  We are getting the student scores and by ranking them so we can quickly see who needs the most help. Give someone a rank or place within a grading system.

Comment: I would add Google spreadsheets to your list of tags. I don’t know about other volunteers here but I don’t deal with cell functions very much. In my own work I do everything in code so I don’t really know how to evaluate cell functions so I can’t help you

Answer (score 0):

The below is pretty a simple utility that can correctly emulate `RANK` formula (including ascending and descending ranking). If you need to make it sort by another column of the range or use [another comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=comparator%20function%20%5Bjavascript%5D%20score%3A10), it is easy to change and make it more versatile.

What you need to do is sort a copy of the target column values by some criteria, get the resulting index, and increment it by `1` since Array indices are `0`-based.

```
/**
 * @summary ranks a range by first column
 * @param {number[][]} range
 * @param {(1|0)} [ascending]
 * @return {number[][]}
 * @customfunction
 */
const rankRange = (values, ascending = 0) => {

    try {

        const rows = values.map(v => v).sort((a, b) => {
            const aParsed = parseFloat(a[0]);
            const bParsed = parseFloat(b[0]);
            return ascending ?
                aParsed - bParsed :
                bParsed - aParsed;
        });

        return values.map((row) => {
            return [rows.findIndex(r => r[0] === row[0]) + 1];
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.warn(`failed to rank column: ${error}`);
        return [[]];
    }
};
```

---

Make sure that the [V8 runtime is enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration) in your project for it to work (or transpile it to ES5 syntax before using).

---

Performance note - usage of `map(v => v)` to shallow copy values is preferential. If you expect the number of items to be high, use `slice()` (thanks to TheMaster's comment, I decided to investigate what the performance hit is). Run the interactive snippet below to see the difference:

```js
const rng = document.querySelector("input[type=range]");

const arr = [];

const bench = (func, lbl) => {
  console.time(lbl);
  func();
  console.timeEnd(lbl);
}

rng.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const {
    value
  } = rng;

  const toAdd = new Array(+value).fill(42);

  arr.length = 0;
  arr.push( ...toAdd );

  bench(() => arr.slice(), "slice");
  bench(() => arr.map(v => v), "map");
});
```

```css
.rng {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<input class="rng" type="range" min="1" max="1e5" step="1">
```

Comment: Why `.map(v=>v)` instead of `slice()`?